# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named celery

Tags: python, celery

Working on the celery upstarting for my flask project. When using the upstart command(`sudo /etc/init.d/celeryd start`) I get

```
celery init v10.1.
Using config script: /etc/default/celeryd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/bin/celery", line 7, in <module>
    from celery.__main__ import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'celery'
```

My bin file for celery is placed in `/home/user/.local/bin/celery`. Directly running `celery -A project worker -l info` in terminal is working fine.

Comment: it looks like module you are working with is called `celery`, rename it to something else, e.g. `my_celery_script` and it should work (or raise another problem)

Comment: @Azat Ibrakov I tried adding a different name for the `celery.py` named previously to `celery_app.py`, still no hope.

Comment: So when you import celery it doesn't work kind of like.... from celery import Celery

Comment: @Joe A, `from celery import Celery` import won't cause any issue here. Only `/etc/init.d/celeryd start` command gives the `ModuleNotFoundError`

Comment: What does your file look like maybe there's an error in there I saw on their docs this maybe itll help http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/tutorials/daemonizing.html

Comment: @KrishV were you able to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 13):

You can install the module `celery` via `pip`.

Make sure `pip` is accessible through the command prompt - if not set it with an environment variable.

Once it's okay then simply type the command

```
pip install celery
```

and the module will be installed.

Comment: Celery is already installed on my machine. Only the celery upstart throws the error. When I use `pip3 show celery`, it shows the version and package information.